# How to count values in one dataframe matching the key from another?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count values in one dataframe matching the key from another.

**What do I have:**

`df_a`:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data = {'keys':['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'total':[0, 0, 0], '>5':''})
df_a
```

output:

```
    keys    total   >5
0   key1    0   
1   key2    0   
2   key3    0
```

`df_b`:

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data = {'keys':['key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key2', 'key3'], 'value':[3, 7, 8, 4, 10]})
df_b
```

Output:

```
    keys    value
0   key1    3
1   key1    7
2   key2    8
3   key2    4
4   key3    10
```

**What I expect:**

I want to count how many values in `df_b` match each key from `df_a`. Also, I want to count which parts of them are more than 5.
As a result, I want to fill my `df_a` like this:

```
    keys    total   >5
0   key1    2       0.5
1   key2    2       0.5
2   key3    1       1.0
```

**What have I done**

I've tried to iterate over column `keys` in `df_b` and `keys` in `df_a`, check if it matches, and then use the local index. But it's finished with an error.

```
for key_a in df_a['keys']:
    for key_b in df_b['keys']:
        if key_a == key_b:
            row_index = df_b.iloc['keys'][key_b]
            df_a['total'][row_index] += 1
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

I know that it's an inefficient way of solving my problem. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove '>5' and 'total' from df_a. that's unnecessary.

```
df_b['>5'] = df_b['value'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 5 else None)

aggs = {'keys': 'first', 'value': 'count', '>5': 'count'}
df_b_new = df_b.groupby('keys').agg(aggs).reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b_new, on='keys', how='left')
df['>5'] = df['>5'] / df['value']
```

OUTPUT:

```
    keys    value   >5
0   key1    2   0.5
1   key2    2   0.5
2   key3    1   1.0
```

EDIT: to change column name from value to Total

```
df.rename(columns={'value': 'total'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new column by compare greater like `5`, then aggregate `size` and `mean` and join to `df_a`:

```
df = (df_b.assign(tmp = df_b['value'].gt(5))
          .groupby('keys')
          .agg(**{'total':('tmp','size'),'>5':('tmp','mean')}))
print (df)
      total   >5
keys            
key1      2  0.5
key2      2  0.5
key3      1  1.0


df = df_a[['keys']].join(df, on='keys')
print (df)
   keys  total   >5
0  key1      2  0.5
1  key2      2  0.5
2  key3      1  1.0
```